# Tsumego intermediate problem 11 - possible without winning ko two times?

Tags: go, tsumego, ko

[This tsumego (intermediate problem 11)](http://tsumego.tasuki.org/books/cho-2-intermediate.pdf) gave me hard time:

[image]

I actually only found a solution where black must win the ko two times, which is nasty. Is there a better solution?

It actually looks like "bent 5" :-)

My solution here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the best you can do.

Comment: Can only agree :)